# How to rewrite web url in apache?

Tags: apache

I have some problem with rewrite URL.

my website is www.abc.com/admin/index.php?nam=123 (admin is folder)

how to rewrite from  www.abc.com/admin/index.php?name=123 to  www.abc.com/admin/123 ?

```
My rewrite: 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  /admin/^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Need result:  www.abc.com/admin/123

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin/([0-9]+)$    index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok. Do you have the `mod_rewrite` module enabled in Apache?

Comment: Yes enable mod_rewrite already. I try type www.abc.com/admin/123 error message: The requested URL /admin/123 was not found on this server. if i type www.abc.com/admin/index.php?name=123 is ok.

Comment: Ok. Is the location to your website correct in `RewriteBase`? `/` means it's in no folder and are in the base folder for the website.

Comment: in www/websitefolder/admin/index.php?name=123. it is correct or not ?

Comment: Well. If you have the .htaccess file in the root of your website (for example abc.com/.htaccess) it should work perfectly. If you have edited `RwwriteRule ^admin/([0-9]+)$` to `www/websitefolder/admin/index.php?name=123` edit it back again because that's wrong.

Comment: Yes it was in root of my website(abc.com/.htaccess) but it not working.The requested URL /admin/123 was not found on this server. I dont know why i was really stress..

Comment: .htaccess in websitefolder (www/websitefolder/admin/index.php?name=123)

Comment: Ok. So the address is for example basiclly `abc.com/websitefolder/index.php?name=123`?

Comment: No. the right is abc.com/websitefolder/admin/index.php?name=123?